# Reputation bug?

Tags: support, reputation

On my [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) account (ELL), my reputation suddenly went down by 2, even though there was nothing in the reputation changes drop down menu. The very next day I received the [Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258) badge, and my reputation went back up by 2, and again there was no information in reputation changes that I got +2 rep.

I'm pretty sure the badge did not cause this. Is it a bug?

Comment: Go check the reputation tab on your profile. Pretty sure you had an unaccept or something. Negative reputation isn't displayed as an achievement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and my reputation went back up by 2

Are you 100% sure of this, or only about the last digit? This is what I see (I'm a ♦ moderator on ELL.SE), and what you can see too if you tick the 'show removed posts' at the bottom of [your reputation tab](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/154090/dialfrost?tab=reputation):

[image]

Both events involve a [Roomba deletion](/help/roomba); yesterday was a question you suggested an edit to; today it was an answer of yours which was deleted along with its parent question.

You're correct about the badge, that's a separate process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it went from 2537 to 2539, not sure how the -8 came about to my rep (I think I forgot someone upvoted my post maybe)